# How to use gcc-code-assist with emacs?

Tags: c++, gcc, emacs, g++, intellisense

I have succesfully built and installed gccsense and gcc-code-assist from source.
I have verified that they have installed properly.
But, there is no change in the way emacs behaves now with c and c++ files(no intellisense still !)

How can I correct this problem ?

I am used these [instructions](http://cx4a.org/software/gccsense/manual.html) to properly build and install gccsense and gcc-code-assist

PS : After reading more about the problem, I found out that to test that everything was installed correctly, we had to run the command `M-x gccsense-diagnose` and a message "Everything OK !" will appear in the minibuffer.

I tried the above command but instead of the message "Everything OK", I get the following error message in a new buffer :-

```
     Cannot obtain completions for std::string
     You may not use code-completion
```

PPS : Here is my ".emacs" `file :-

```
        (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/")  
(load "gccsense.el") 
(load "auto-complete.el") 

(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 )
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :background "black" :foreground "gainsboro" :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 128 :width normal :foundry "unknown" :family "Ubuntu Mono")))))
(defun switch-fullscreen nil
  (interactive)
  (let* ((modes '(nil fullboth fullwidth fullheight))
         (cm (cdr (assoc 'fullscreen (frame-parameters) ) ) )
         (next (cadr (member cm modes) ) ) )
    (modify-frame-parameters
     (selected-frame)
     (list (cons 'fullscreen next)))))

(define-key global-map [f11] 'switch-fullscreen)

 ; (global-auto-complete-mode t)
```

Answer (score 0):

did you do that?
Write the following code into ~/.emacs

```
(require 'gccsense)
```

Comment: can you send your .emacs please and your emacs version.

Comment: just follow this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sz68cCQ0Zpc and send your emacs version please.